# Controller Action calling in different ways in Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, jquery, zend-paginator

my Controller action

```
public function abcsajaxAction(){
  $start_date = $this->_getParam('start_date');
  $end_date   = $this->_getParam('end_date');


  $myquery; //myquery
  //zend pagination
  }
```

i call this action from here i mean my js

```
$("#show_history_call_logs").click(function(){
 var pass = true;
 var start_date    = $("#start_date").val();
 var end_date      = $("#end_date").val();
 var page_to_get   = $('input[name=hidden]').val();

 //some validation
 if(pass == true){
var href= "http://localhost/abc/xyz/index.php/login/"+page_to_get+"/";
var data ='start_date=' + start_date + '&end_date=' + end_date + '&option_call_log=' + option_call_log + '&option_call_log_asc_desc=' + option_call_log_asc_desc;
 $.ajax({ type: "GET",
           url: href,
          data: data,
          success: function(response){
           $('#paged-data-container').html(response);
            }
           });
           return false;
        }
```

now on this event i mean 
       `$("#show_history_call_logs").click()`

its work fine every time
**but as i said there is pagination too in this action** so now when i click on any of pagination so they go to this action but as they are  NOT getting These

```
$start_date = $this->_getParam('start_date');
$end_date   = $this->_getParam('end_date');
```

in this case its giving me this error

```
Message: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound
```

which in other side they are getting i mean through event.
so how should i go so that it work in both scene .

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand what exactly you want to achieve. You have start and end date in your sql query. So you should

- set the params
- rewrite your query so that dates are not considered if not present

For example in this manner

> `$start_date = $this->_getParam('start_date', null);`
>
> `...`
>
> `$sql = $this->select()->from(x);`
>
> `if(!empty($startDate)) {`
>
> `$sql->where('start_date < ?', $startDate)`
>
> `}`

Comment: i want the same query that is applied before but now different pages mean that firstly it renders page now page 2 and so on.how i ll do this

Comment: what doe null means here $start_date = $this->_getParam('start_date', null);

Comment: If you have params in your query they have to be filled, is this not clear? :) Second param is default value that is set if no param is present.


If you want pagination you should read paginator docs - http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.paginator.html

Answer (score 0):

not tested but try may be it works

```
if(empty($start_date) && empty($end_date)){
$select = $registry['select']; 
   }
else{
      $select; //your new query
 }

 if(!empty($start_date) && !empty($end_date)){
   Zend_Registry::set('select',$select);
  }
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: select